# How ||= and unless include? differe?

Tags: ruby

What are the differences between the 2 following line ?

```
# settings and globals are Hash
@settings[:xvfb] = globals[:xvfb] unless settings.include?(:xvfb)
@settings[:xvfb] ||= globals[:xvfb]
```

Are they equivalent ?

Comment: Depends on what `settings` is.

Comment: `settings` and `globals` are `Hash`. Question updated.

Comment: @AlexandreArdhuin: In addition to what Sergio said: You have a typo. I guess you mean `unless @settings.include?(:xvfb)`.

Comment: @user1934428: or it is an `attr_reader`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, they are not equivalent. They differ in handling falsey values.

```
globals = { foo: 'bar' }

h = { foo: nil }
h.include?(:foo) # => true
h[:foo] = globals[:foo] unless h.include?(:foo)
h # => {:foo=>nil}

h = { foo: nil }
h[:foo] ||= globals[:foo]
h # => {:foo=>"bar"}
```

Comment: Also worth noting that very frequently this difference is academic and irrelevant. It depends entirely on the type of data you're dealing with. If you can be sure it's not `nil` or `false`, then `||=` will do the job with less fuss.

Comment: @tadman: True. But when it's used for caching, it does make a huge difference if `expensive_method` returns say, a huge array or `nil`.

Comment: @EricDuminil Absolutely. That's why being aware of the values you're dealing with is paramount. If you can design that method to return an empty array or hash instead of `nil`, that might help interface things better.